# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

нужна ли в предложении "С умным Разговориться что мёду напиться" запятая???

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна. Сравнительный союз что (=как) стоит перед сказуемым. Между подлежащим и сказуемым( разговориться что напиться)запятые не ставятся.

Answer (score 1):

Запятой здесь быть не может, только тире, и то как авторский знак.

Comment: Меня тоже потянуло на тире...

Answer (score -2):

Нужна. Сравнительные обороты выделяются запятыми всегда, кроме двух случаев:

- сравнительный оборот является устойчивым выражением;
- сравнительный оборот образует собой сказуемое.

**UPD:** [Ссылка](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/34045/%D0%A1) для тех, кто считает, что запятой здесь быть не может.

**UPD2:** [Ccылка](http://www.gramota.ru/class/poslovitsy/?alpha=%D1) для тех, для кого Даль не является авторитетом.

Comment: Нет, уважаемый, не всегда. Если сравнительный оборот является сказуемым, то ни тире, ни запятая не ставится( Примеры из Розенталя: Пруд как блестящая сталь. Ты меж сестер словно горлинка белая промежду сизых простых голубей)

Comment: Согласен. Ещё пример: жизнь как чудо.

Comment: Справка для тех, что считает, что запятая тут быть может.
Владимир Иваноыич Даль не имел филологического образрования и умер 4 октября 1872 ст. ст.

Comment: @Shamov, а при чем тут Даль? 
Он на gramota.ru не писал.
А кто выверял пунктуацию в тех сборниках - неизвестно. Явно не Розенталь.